# gcc shows different warnings depending on optimisation level

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

I compiled a C program with `-O0 -Wall` and then `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3` and I received different warning messages, some of them actually important enough that they showed actual bugs (for instance a function returning a string that was local instead of static in `-O1` IIRC).

Why is that ? Can I get *more* warnings ?

Comment: What version of GCC? And can you try to create a [mcve] which replicates the behavior and show it to us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some optimization levels of gcc analyze the code a bit more deeply than others, which can also lead to the detection of errors. One example is loop optimization, that is performed from optimization level 2 on.

Consider this code:

```
void func (void) {
    char buf[9];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        buf[i] = i;
}
```

If you compile it with O0 or O1, no loop optimization is performed. But on level O2 and upwards, the compiler detects, that the last loop iteration invokes undefined behaviour:

```
main.c:5:10: warning: iteration 9 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   buf[i] = i;
   ~~~~~~~^~~
main.c:4:2: note: within this loop
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  ^~~
```

So yes, heavy optimizations can help detecting bugs because gcc puts more effort into analyzing the code for optimization purposes.

**Edit:**

For this specific warning, actually the *Value Range Propagation* optimization (-ftree-vrp) is responsible.

From the gcc documentation:

> This is similar to the constant propagation pass, but instead of values, ranges of values are propagated. This allows the optimizers to remove unnecessary range checks like array bound checks and null pointer checks. This is enabled by default at -O2 and higher. Null pointer check elimination is only done if -fdelete-null-pointer-checks is enabled.

**Edit 2:**

The observations may differ with the gcc version; in this case, gcc version *8.3.0* was used.

Comment: Please specify on which gcc version did you run the loop code. I tried it with gcc 4.4.6, and I did not get a warning using -O2.
I did get a warning when I used -O3: warning: array subscript is above array bounds

Comment: @EliyahuMachluf I added this information to the answer